# How to display name and grade for a student in a dictiionary who has the highest grade

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a brand new to programming and I'm stuck on a practice exercise.

EDIT: exact error code "avgDict[k] =max(sum(v)/ float(len(v)))

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"

If I remove max it's printing every student's avg.

```
# student_grades contains scores (out of 100) for 5 assignments
diction = {
    'Andrew': [56, 79, 90, 22, 50],
    'Colin': [88, 62, 68, 75, 78],
    'Alan': [95, 88, 92, 85, 85],
    'Mary': [76, 88, 85, 82, 90],
    'Tricia': [99, 92, 95, 89, 99]
}

def averageGrades(diction):
    avgDict = {}
    for k, v in diction.items():
          avgDict[k] =max(sum(v)/ float(len(v)))
    return avgDict
```

Comment: I DID! my mistake, I updated it!

Comment: no problem, I saw your update so I deleted my comment

Comment: Where's the call to `averageGrades`? What's the full error message? See [mre] for reference. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: This might help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-average-list-python/

Comment: Did you want to print out the highest name and grade or return the highest name and grade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code is doing right now is iterating through each key-value pair of the dictionary (where the key is the student's name and the value is the list of the student's grades), and then calculating the average for the student. Then, the way you are using `max` right now, it is trying to find the max of a single student's average. This is why you are receiving the error, because `max` expects either an iterable or multiple parameters, and a `float` (which is the value produced by `sum(v) / float(len(v))`) is not an iterable. You should instead compute all of the averages first, and then find the max value in the dictionary of averages:

```
diction = {
    'Andrew': [56, 79, 90, 22, 50],
    'Colin': [88, 62, 68, 75, 78],
    'Alan': [95, 88, 92, 85, 85],
    'Mary': [76, 88, 85, 82, 90],
    'Tricia': [99, 92, 95, 89, 99]
}

def averageGrades(diction):
    avgDict = {}
    for k, v in diction.items():
          avgDict[k] = sum(v) / len(v)

    return max(avgDict.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]) # find the pair which has the highest value

print(averageGrades(diction)) # ('Tricia', 94.8)
```

Sidenote, in Python 3, using `/` does normal division (as opposed to integer division) by default, so casting `len(v)` to a `float` is unnecessary.

Alternatively, if you don't need to create the `avgDict` variable, you can just determine the max directly without the intermediate variable:

```
def averageGrades(diction):
    return max([(k, sum(v) / len(v)) for k, v in diction.items()], key=lambda i: i[1])

print(averageGrades(diction)) # ('Tricia', 94.8)
```

Comment: @Kamron no problem